# Adding filter values dynamically to a dashboard possible?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, dashboard

The Setup:

I am doing some report hacking, where at runtime the values of certain report filters are added. That part is working.

The problem:

Business wants charts created, and displayed on the user's homepage, (so dashboards, or dashboard like behavior).  Is there a way to do this? It doesn't have to be in real-time, maybe once a week.  One concern I have is that these are generic reports that are shared across multiple users, but the records displayed will be different based on the user.

Comment: thanks eyescream. Time to look for work arounds then....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass in parameters to dashboards. Have you looked at using dynamic dashboards to run as the user viewing it? This will automatically change the view per user.

If you have additional filters you need to do, you'd have to build something custom with a Visualforce page. You could use [iframes to embed reports in the page](http://vanityforce.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/displaying-a-report-within-visualforce/). Or you could use something like [Visualforce Charts](http://www.verticalcoder.com/2012/10/24/visualforce-charting-another-way-to-visualize-data/) or [Google Visualization](http://www.verticalcoder.com/2011/07/19/salesforce-data-visualization/) to recreate the dashoard components.